# Change remote URL of a forked project

Tags: git, github, repository, git-remote

I've forked a project, then made my own changes with relative branches. I can see my branch progress on: *Insights->Network* of original project. I want change the repository url of my contributions. So I can see my work on another repository.

I've tried to do **git remote set-url origin (*https://url*)**, and successfully updated repository url.*(Checked it by doing git remote -v)*. But when I look into the repository I've created, I can not see my project in there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the remote locally won't have any impact on GitHub side.

You still need to push your work to that new URL, in order to see your project at that new URL.